# Chrome-extension: Auto updating not working?

Tags: xml, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I've been trying to get my Chrome extension to auto update but it doesn't appear to be working. I've followed Google's tutorial at http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/autoupdate.html but still had no luck. I've got the following...

**In my Manifest file**

```
    "update_url": "http://www.example.com/updates.xml",
```

**updates.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
 <gupdate xmlns='http://www.google.com/update2/response' protocol='2.0'> 
  <app appid='dmsdmaksadsdkdsmsasdmk'> 
    <updatecheck codebase='http://www.example.com/myapp_1_5.crx' version='1.5.1' /> 
  </app> 
 </gupdate>
```

If I update my app to `1.5.2` and change my manifest version + the updates.xml URL and version and hit update extensions in the extesions menu in Chrome my extension will not update. Does anyone know why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you packaging the new version with the same pem secret Chrome generated when you packaged the first version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at your updates.xml file, it seems you placed the incorrect appid (Extension ID) your missing 10 characters for it. It should contain 32 characters not 22 characters.

Other than that, everything else looks good.